# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to implement `cordova-plugin-email-composer`.I installed the plugin using `cli`

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git`

I got an error  `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined  at email_composer.js:22.`

In the [link](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) u can find the plugin. I added the code attached below in my `index.js` file. Can anyone help to solve this? Thankyou.

**index.js:**

```
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, function () {
        cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
            function (isAvailable) {
                alert("is email mobile available? " + (isAvailable ? "Yes" : "No"));
                if(isAvailable){
                 window.plugin.email.open({
                     to:      'anu.barbie143@gmail.com',
                     subject: 'Greetings',
                     body:    'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig'
                 }, callback, scope);
               }
            }
        );
    }, false);

    function callback(){
        console.log("callback function");
    }

    function scope(){
        console.log("scope function");
    }

},
```

email_composer.js:

```
var exec      = require('cordova/exec'),
isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1,
mailto    = 'mailto:';
```

In the above code i got an error require is not defined.Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thankyou.

Comment: which version of email-composer are you using ?

Comment: version-0.8.3@Hiten

Comment: once removed the plugin and will add again. And did you get alert "is email mobile available ... " ?

Comment: I tried remove and then add same error coming again.No i dint get the alert.@Hiten

Comment: You didn't refer directly to `email_composer.js` from `index.html`, right?

Comment: I referred email_composer.js in index.html @EddyVerbruggen

Comment: You should not do that. Just refer to cordova.js. If installed properly it will require all plugins for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by doing following

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-email-composer
```

then add the plugin with version 0.8.2,by following command since there is an open error in plugin version 0.8.3 for loolipop

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git#0.8.2
```

index.js

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
    // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');

                cordova.plugins.email.open({
                    to:      'test@gmail.com',
                    cc:      'test@gmail.com',
                    bcc:     [],
                    subject: 'Greetings',
                    body:    'How are you? Nice greetings from Naresh'
                });



    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and its working now.
So please check it once.

```
cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(function (isAvailable) {
                // alert('Service is not available') unless isAvailable;
                alert("is email mobile available? " + (isAvailable ? "Yes" : "No"));
                if(isAvailable){
                    window.plugin.email.open({
                        to:      'test@test.com',
                        subject: 'Greetings',
                        body:    'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
                    }, function(){
                        console.log('email view dismissed');
                    },
                    this);
                }
            });
```

if alert is "no" it means you don't have any email application or configuration.